# Mysql: UPDATE column3 IF column1 is changed

Tags: mysql

I have this query where I increase a `INT` with 1 if `DUPLICATE KEY`.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table(
                  column1,
                  column2)
            VALUES(
                  value1,
                  value2)
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                  column1 = VALUES(column1),
                  column2 = VALUES(column2),
                  column3 = column3+1";  //HERE!!!
```

Column1 is UNIQUE. So if value of column1 exist in DB `UPDATE` will run.
 I do **not** want `coulmn3` to increase if `column1` AND `column2` haven't changed to new values.

How can I solve that?

```
...
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
   column1 = VALUES(column1),
   column2 = VALUES(column2),

//Something like this
IF (column1 != VALUES(column1) && column2 != VALUES(column2){
   column3 = column3+1}";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically there right?

```
$query = <<<SQL
INSERT INTO targetTable(col1, col2)
VALUES(2, 3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
   col3 = IF(
      col1 = VALUES(col1) AND col2 = VALUES(col2),
      col3,
      col3 + 1
   ),
   col1 = VALUES(col1),
   col2 = VALUES(col2)
;
SQL;
```

SQLFiddle demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/70fdea/1

This works by setting `column3` to the result of the `IF()` statement, like you were proposing before.

`IF(condition, trueResult, falseResult)`

So we check if anything has changed, return the same `column3` (no change) if nothing's changed and `+1` otherwise.

Note I've swapped the logic of your conditional statement - you were checking that **both** columns had changed (but had stated that either changing should affect `column3`).  Also the `UPDATE` specifically handles `column3` first - otherwise the other columns have already updated and can't be compared against.)

Also make sure your schema has a default value of 0 (zero) for column 3.

Comment: I will give this a try. Thank you. What is "<<<SQL" for ?

Comment: <<<SQL is "heredoc" format - it is (IMHO) vastly better suited for blocks of strings (text) like SQL.  Some editors even highlight the SQL appropriately if you use this specific format: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: I've just realised my syntax was valid - but the results will be wrong ... I'll update, sorry about that.

Comment: Fixed it - my apologies, I'm half asleep.  I'll throw up an SQL fiddle to demo it shortly...

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/70fdea/1 <-- proof :)  Updating column3 before the others is critical (I hadn't realised until I ran it in SQLFiddle)

Comment: Thank you very much @wally!